# How to move the arrow to the right in the input field?

Tags: html, css

```css
.wrapper-dropdown-3 {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.1);
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #8AA8BD;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-3:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-top: -3px;
  border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #8aa8bd transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-3" tabindex="1">
  <span>Transport</span>
</div>
```

In the above code I want to insert the blue arrow to the middle right of the `.wrapper-dropdown-3`. As of now it is situated on the top right near the Transport `span`. I am not sure how I can move it to the very right middle? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use absolute positioning against container:

```css
.wrapper-dropdown-3 {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;

    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 7px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.1);
    cursor: pointer;

    font-weight: bold;
    color: #8AA8BD;

    position: relative;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-3:after {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-top: -3px;
    border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #8aa8bd transparent;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: calc(50% + 6px / 2); /* 6px here is border-width value to compensate a fact that arrow is made from border */
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-3" tabindex="1">
 <span>Transport</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah ok perfect it's now in the center. Do you know why we need absolute positioning since the `after` psuedo selector should place it after the div correct?

Comment: `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements dictates browser to place generated elements (with text content taken from `content` style) as first and last **children** of the element, not before and after element itself. Please refer [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) for more information

Comment: Ohh so essentially `after` would place it after the `span` inside of the `wrapper-dropdown-3` div. Got it thank you!

Comment: Just curious since the content is `""` how does it form the upside down triangle? I got this code from a tutorial for creating drop down menus but not sure how the triangle gets formed if the content is empty? Does it have to do with the `border-width` property?

Comment: Yes, this triangle came from the border. Actually it is top border of the empty square that, as you can imagine, forms a triangle. `border-color` adds color to the `border-top` and make all other borders invisible. Since size of the element is `0x0` - tip of the top border goes to zero size and forms a triangle. But since actual total size of the element is twice more (because there is other borders despite of the fact that they're invisible) it is necessary to use additional compensation of `size / 2` into `calc()` applied to the `top: 50%`

Answer (score 0):

Simply use positionning like this :

```css
.wrapper-dropdown-3 {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.1);
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #8AA8BD;
  /*Code added*/
  position:relative;
  /**/
}

.wrapper-dropdown-3:after {
  /*Code added*/
  position:absolute;
  right:5px;
  top:50%;
  /**/
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-top: -3px;
  border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #8aa8bd transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-3" tabindex="1">
  <span>Transport</span>
</div>
```

Comment: How come I have to use positioning for this? I thought the `after` pseudo class will place it after the div?

Comment: Absolute value for the `top` is bad idea because there is no fixed height is defined in container element

Comment: @Flying yes sure, but my intention was to show him the use of positioning ;) then we can adjuste the values :)

Comment: i fix it by the way ;)